# document.getElementById for a "div" alerting [object HTMLDivElement] instead of "thisDiv"

Tags: javascript

Why does my function alert `[object HTMLDivElement]` instead of `thisDiv`?

```
<div id="myId">thisDiv</div>
<script>
    function x() {
        var x1 = document.getElementById("myId");
        alert(x1);
    }
    x();
</script>
```

Comment: Please confirm what actually you want to do so we can help accordingly.

Comment: This is happening because Alert displays stringify object, for more details on object, use console.dir

Comment: Because the alert displays ths object. You can use console.log(x1) and check it in the web console.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="myId">thisDiv</div>
<script>
    function x() {
        var x1 = document.getElementById("myId");
        alert(x1.innerText);
    }
    x();
</script>
```

x1 is an HTML element and is displayed as such. To get `"thisDiv"`, you have to extract text from it with `innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use textContent, like this.

```
<div id="myId">thisDiv</div>
<script>
    function x() {
        var x1 = document.getElementById("myId").textContent;
        alert(x1);
    }
    x();
</script>
```